# What Type should I assign to an Index

Tags: typescript, expo

**color** is a string that defaults to **primary**
but when passed into the **Colors** array as an **index** I'm promptly informed that it's an ***any*** type because a string can't be used as an index on type '{..etc}'
[image: Screenshot from 2021-06-05 03-33-33]
**Colors** are just the default constants with the tab template out of Expo, but I'm extending the color palette.
[image: Screenshot from 2021-06-05 03-41-01]

I'm still fairly new to typescript, but I don't think there is an index type..
***So my question is what should I be setting its type to?***

I've tried changing it to sting[] or string{}, but I'm still getting the same warning

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ primary: string; secondary: string; black: string; white: string; darkGrey: string; mediumGrey: string; lightGrey: string; danger: string; light: { text: string; background: string; tint: string; tabIconDefault: string; tabIconSelected: string; }; dark: { ...; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ primary: string; secondary: string; black: string; white: string; darkGrey: string
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native'

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

interface AppButtonProps {
  color?: string;
  title?: string;
  onPress?: any;
}

const AppButton: React.FC<AppButtonProps> = ({
  color = 'primary',
  title = 'default App Button',
  onPress = () => console.log('default AppButton'),
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: Colors[color] }]}
        onPress={onPress}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 15,
    width: "100%",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  text: {
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 18,
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
})

export default AppButton
```

**update:**
After the first few comments, I broke out the palette as a separate file to replace `color`. I was trying to piggyback on the `constants.Colors` that Expo's Tab Template comes with out of the box.

should I be trying to assign string type to the export. I noticed Colors had a note from typescript that it would only allow light or dark for the theming. Should I be saying this object can only have primary, secondary etc? or should I just be looking for where an interface is already set on the Color object?

```js
export default {
  primary: "#fc5c65",
  secondary: "#4ecdc4",
  black: "#000",
  white: "#fff",
  darkGrey: "#0c0c0c",
  mediumGrey: "#6e6969",
  lightGrey: "#f8f4f4",
  danger: "#ff5252",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `color?: string[];` to `color?: string;`.

In your code, your are telling typescript that a color is a string array, and I believe you are not trying to access your colors by an array.

For example, if your are trying to get the primary color, you access the value by `Colors["primary"]` or `Colors.primary`. If you are using former, the value inside of the square brackets must be a string as opposed to a `string[]`.

> Color is a string that defaults to primary but when passed into the Colors array as an index I'm promptly informed

More importantly, `Colors` is not an array, it is an object.

Comment: I've tried all three;
string, sting {} and string [] and tend to still get the same error

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the original error message after switching to `string` please?

Comment: It might be the nested objects in `Colors` that's causing the error, try removing it or commenting it temporarily

Comment: I commented out the light and dark and it added a new line I hadn't seen before in the warning..
`No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ primary: string; secondary: string; black:`
so should I be trying to add types in the the Color file?

Comment: I don't think you have to explicitly tell typescript that the values are strings.

Answer (score 0):

> `backgroundColor` only requires string type. It cannot accept any value except string.

As your default export `Colors` is an object whose values are the union of string and object type, so the `backgroundColor` throws a compile-time error that it cannot accept an object and can accept the only string type.

You need to move out the dark and light properties from the default export Colors. Create a context provider of your theme and share this context across your project.